# .Net Serialization Idea Needed

Tags: c#, serialization

```
public class Page
{
    public List<Point> Points;
    public List<Line> Lines;

}

public class Point
{
    public double X, Y;
    public Page Parent;
}

public class Line
{
    public Point StartPoint;
    public Point EndPoint;
    public Page Parent;
}
```

at initilizing time of Line Object It Will Checked That StartPoint and EndPoint Be In Line's Parent.
i need a idead that can serialize and deserialize a Page  (or save and retrive it from a file) object fully but it will result in cyrcular refrence...
take me some idea to do this...
thanks...

Comment: Can't you just use .NET XML serialization? Fairly simple to use.

Comment: no. for example StartPoint and EndPoint of all Line Objects must reference be Those Who Are In Points Property of Parent Structure. by your idead this not happens. i sayd true?

Answer (score 2):

If you use XML serialization you can mark the properties that would lead to circular references with `XmlIgnore` so they won't be serialized, hence avoiding the problem i.e:

```
public class Point
{
    public double X, Y;
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Page Parent;
}

public class Line
{
    public Point StartPoint;
    public Point EndPoint;
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Page Parent;
}
```

If you really need your own serialization, you could have a similar attribute - but I wouldn't recommend reinventing the wheel - just use what's already built in.

Also as a side note you should really use properties instead of public fields in your classes.

Comment: i need that Parent object refrences to a Page that is parent of current point and line.

Comment: @qiback: @Thomas Levesque has a blog post about this particular topic (maintaining parent-child relationship with serialization) : http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2009/06/12/c-parentchild-relationship-and-xml-serialization/ - this might work for you

Answer (score 1):

If you want the full graph serialized, DataContractSerializer can do that, but only with the `preserveObjectReferences` option enabled in the constructor. Personally, I would just serialize the downwards relationships, and fixup the parent navigations only.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) this a great library with very good configuration options for dealing with many edge cases such as this one.
http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/